# Laravel 5.4 - Create Another User Account while already logged in

Tags: php, laravel, forms, routes

I'm learning Laravel at the moment and am stuck adding user accounts from an existing account. I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` on line 251 when I submit my form. This is normally related to not matching a post in web.php with a post form, but adding this hasn't resolved anything.

I believe everything is declared correctly but would appreciate any pointers if you see anything amiss.

**adduser.blade**

```
<div id="form-header">
    Create another user account
</div>
<div id="form-container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <!--form variable-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- form inputs -->
        </div>

        <div class=" form-group">
            <button type="submit">
                Create
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/adduser', 'AddUserController@index');
Route::post('/adduser', 'AddUserController@create_user');
```

**addusercontroller**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('adduser');
}

public function create_user(Request $request)
{
    return User::create(['input' => '$request->input']);
}
```

Comment: It's the route that it's tripping over, not the rest of it. I'd suggest adding an action to your form so that it's clear which route it needs to hit.

Comment: Is it though? If you're on `/adduser`, and you submit a `POST` form without `action`, it should post to the current URL, which is `/adduser`.

Comment: I would have thought not setting action would also set it to the current url, but had tried setting an action as well to no change

Comment: I kinda think your return statement isn't correct. Should probably be `User::create(...); return redirect("/adduser");` or a `redirect` to somewhere else.

Comment: my working code currently allows existing user to update db info fine, so I was copying that template. Thanks Tim I'll look at changing the return statement and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two errors here, although the second wasn't included in my question (fatal throwable error I think). I had to add use app/user in the adduser controller, and for the initial routing error this was human error, I had two blades with the same name but one had a capital, and I was editing the wrong file. I've deleted this and put in the code from above in the correct blade which worked.

Just a personal note: You don't need to declare the method action if you're working from the current url as was mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified that the form should be a POST, but you haven't specified the route to post to.

Change

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{url('adduser')}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks but I had tried something like this. I'll try a few other variants and maybe it'll like one of them...